# Как сделать рендеринг состояния на сервере?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, redux, react-router

Делаю рендеринг на сервере с redux и react-router. Состояние инициализирую дефолтное. Как я понял `renderToString()` не делает запрос к api который выполняется у меня в `componentDidMount()`. Из-за этого на сервере рендерится просто компонент лоадинга, а не нужный мне список.

**UPD:**
код на сервере server.js:

```
const renderToString = reactDomServer.renderToString
const match = reactRouter.match
const RouterContext = reactRouter.RouterContext

app.get('*', (req, res, next) => {
      const error = () => res.status(404).send('404')
      const htmlFilePath = path.join( __dirname, '../build', 'index.html' )

      fs.readFile( htmlFilePath, 'utf8', (err, htmlData) => {
        if(err) {
          error()
        }
        else {
          match({ routes, location: req.url }, (err, redirect, ssrData) => {
            if(err) {
              error()
            }
            else if(redirect) {
              res.redirect(302, redirect.pathname + redirect.search)
            }
            else if(ssrData) {

              const store = createStore(rootReducer)
              const ReactApp = renderToString(
                react.createElement(Provider, {store},
                  react.createElement(RouterContext, ssrData)
                )
              )
              const preloadedState = store.getState()

              const storeServer = `
              <script>
                window.__PRELOADED_STATE__ = ${JSON.stringify(preloadedState).replace(/</g, '\\u003c')}
              </script>
            `

              let RenderedApp = htmlData.replace('{{SSR}}', ReactApp).replace('{{storeScript}}', storeServer)

              res.status(200).send(RenderedApp)
            }
            else {
              error()
            }
          })
        }
      })
    });
```

код компонента на клиенте:

```
  class PostsWrapper extends Component {

      componentDidMount() {
        const { dispatch, page } = this.props
        dispatch(fetchPosts(page))
      }

      render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <Posts posts={this.props.posts}/>
          </div>
        )
      }
    }

    function mapStateToProps (state) {
      return {
        page: state.page,
        posts: state.posts
      }
    }

    export default connect(mapStateToProps)(PostsWrapper)
```

`fetchPosts()` Делает запрос к api. Как мне сделать на сервере запрос к api и получить данные для рендера на сервере если допустим для разных компонентов запросы идут к разным url api. То-есть для компонента `Posts` запрос идет api идет к `api.site.com/posts` а для компонента `User` запрос будет `api.site.com/user/id`.

Answer (score 0):

componentDidMount() - вызывается только на клиенте.

Вам нужно ставить сразу устанавливать нужное состояние на сервере.

Comment: В этом и вопрос, я не знаю как получить состояние на сервере. Точнее я получил начальное состояние на сервере, но как при рендере передать урл, сделать запрос к нужному апи и получить нужное состояние?

Comment: @DarkSir я что, то не пойму проблему. У вас стоит условие в   componentDidMount() ???
Скиньте компонент в вопрос

Comment: Я немного разобрался, и понял что на сервере нужно сразу сделать запрос чтобы состояние получить. Но не понял как мне делать запрос к нужному api. То-есть как определить каким компонентам к какому апи нужно запрос сделать

Comment: @DarkSir ну так сделайте прелоад с сервера и положите в кэш, а в экшенах с запросами смотрите кэш ,и если нет данных, грузите с апи, и снова в кеш складывайте...